# What is the max number of Blocks which can be created in Quorum

Tags: web3js, remix, private-blockchain, quorum, blocks

I have nodes running from past few days, with almost 4100+ transactions successfully completed. When i try to interact with the contracts again to add/modify details it shows error

**Error when interacted through web3js application**
[image]

**Error when interacting through remix browser**
[image]

The same transactions made when block number was below 4000 worked absolutely fine. So, i have a doubt is there is any limit on how many blocks can be created in Quorum network.

Can anyone please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Transaction is being recorded but mining failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no limit on the number of blocks. It's possible there is an error in your contract or web3.js code which is only manifesting after a number of iterations. Also, make sure you're still passing the correct parameters to your contract.

If I search for that error message "BigNumber Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number", then I can find a number of different causes.